# Data Masking options is exist in Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-masking

I have a Database with secure Data in some tables(5 tables) when I bring that Database into my Local Environment I need to Mask the Data with Special Characters.

For Example :

Table 1 :

```
Name Code 
Mohan 100
Raju  200
```

I need to see the data like this

```
    Name Code 
    M@#$n 1#0
    R@#u  2#@
```

for some of the tables which some sensitive Data

When I get the DB backup with all this data when I'm restoring the Data into my local I need to see the data like this .

Can you please suggest me the best ways or any features in SQL server to mask the Data.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: MSSQL... @jarlh

Comment: I would suggest that for sensitive data you only need to look towards that data which can be used to identify someone/thing/company, and then replace the whole name with one formed via a randomizer.

Comment: store the data encrypted or scrambled in the database and let the client software decrypt or de-scramble it

Comment: SQL Server 2016 has Dynamic Data Masking: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt130841.aspx. There is nothing easy to use I'm aware of for older versions.

Comment: @LogicalMan Can you please elaborate what you mean by  randomizer.

Comment: @GuidoG any examples on scramble or encrypted

Comment: What is your version of SQL server???

Comment: Sql server 2012 @ajeh

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve that in a single backup/restore step using only SQL Server 2012. You will either need to write some masking scripts and use those in an ETL workflow or you could consider some data masking products that offer on-the-fly masking (masks the data while copying from source to destination).

If you don't want to write your own masking scripts to do this then you could use the free [DataVeil Platform data masking tool](https://www.dataveil.com/dataveil-platform/) and use the Redact mask. Disclaimer: I work for DataVeil.